# Display image from byte array

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have image byte array stored in session.

```
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])Session["STORED_IMAGE"];
```

I want display this in image control after postback. I have tried this code

```
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])Session["STORED_IMAGE"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sandra");
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
    Response.End();
```

It displays the image. but also downloads it. I just want to display not download.
Can anyone help me doing this?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just remove that line

```
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=sandra");
```

This line gives the "command" and browser starts to download it.

### Update

If I understand well, you try to show this image on a certain place on the page.
But I also understand that you add that code on the same page with the rest code. This can not work because you "break" the page.

Make a handler `.ashx` and there place that code.

Then from your page, call that handler as

`<img src="showimage.ashx" />`

and there you see it.

Comment: I have tried with that. Then other contents disappears and only the image appears

Comment: @Sandra If you have add this code on post back and overwrite the page flow, then you have other issues... Make a handler and show your image called from the handler

Comment: I had tried with this handler                                                             public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var imageData = context.Session["STORED_IMAGE"] as byte[];
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

Comment: If I add it in Handler, the image does not display

Comment: @Sandra Do you see what error you get there ? Probably you do not have add the session on the handler. I say that because you use session. Open the results from the handler or debug it to see your errors ... read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181408/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-ashx-file/14181556#14181556

Comment: @Sandra Well, probably the session is not have the time to write that data, or I do not know...., you need to design it show other way to make it work. Your design is the main issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add handler

with parameter

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx?VehicleCode=" + Eval("VehicleCode")%>'>
```

without parameter

```
 <asp:Image runat="server" Width="40px" Height="40px" ImageUrl='<%# "Handler.ashx %>'>
```

inside handler get image from db and pass as this

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

      //if you pass parameter use this
        string para = context.Request.QueryString["VehicleCode"];

      //get the image from data base in here im using a web service
        System.Data.DataSet ds = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MMS_MasterWebService.MMS_MasterMaintenance obj = new MMS_MasterWebService.MMS_MasterMaintenance();
        obj.Url =  "http://192.168.48.10/SHOREVision_MMS_Service/MMS_MasterMaintenance.asmx";
        ds = obj.GetVehicleMasterByCode(para);
        context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][21]);

    }
```

Comment: @sandra use this link for see how to create handler and show image on web page http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx