# ASHX and concurrent call with long process

Tags: asp.net, web

Am I right with my assuption of how ashx handle requests?

Call 1 -> contact the file -> enter the ashx -> long process

Call 2 -> concatact the file -> wait for call 1 to end -> enter the ashx -> long pocess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Request to handlers are **run in parallel**.

There is one exception if you have connected with the session, then its work as you mention.

Read also:
[HttpContext.Current.Session is null in Ashx file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14181408/httpcontext-current-session-is-null-in-ashx-file/14181556#14181556)
[Does ASP.NET Web Forms prevent a double click submission?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11629600/does-asp-net-web-forms-prevent-a-double-click-submission/11629664#11629664)

Comment: Thx! I was not aware of the session locking thing.